# sumar valores de input y restarlos de ser necesario

Tags: javascript, jquery, algoritmos

Buen dia, tengo el siguiente script el cual suma los valores en tiempo real de 5 input, todos ellos tienen la clase input_valores_provisionales y los muestra en un span de id total_provisionales

la cuestion es que si por ejemplo la suma va en 20 al momento de digitar cualquiera de ellos y por error humano en uno de ellos no iba un 5 si no un 3, al borrar el 5 y poner la suma deberia ser 17 y no 20 ya que estaría restando realmente un 2

pues resulta que sigue sumando sin freno, me muestra 23

lo que se me ocurre es que debería primero validar que valor hay actualmente, lo hice con:

```
valor_actual=$(this).val();
```

para luego compararlo con el valor nuevo introducido y así sumar o restar la diferencia, intenté hacerlo pero me toma el valor escrito ya que como la funcion esta con el evento "change" pues en realidad me tomará el valor nuevo digitado y no el que ya estaba, aquí el código sin la linea que intenté

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //guardara el total
  var total = 0;

  //cuando haya un cambio en el input 
  $('.input_valores_provisionales').change(function() {

    //valido que sea un numero
    if (!isNaN($(this).val()))
    {

       //va acumulando el total
      total += Number($(this).val());

      //muestra el total en el span
      $("#total_provisionales").text("$"+total);
    }
    else
    {
      //Si no introduce numero genera alerta
      alert("Debe ingresar un valor numerico");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra opcion usando Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //cada vez que el usuario orpime una tacla
  $('input').keyup(function() {
    var total = 0;

    //recorremos los input para que haga la suma
    $("input").each(
      function() {
        if (Number($(this).val())) {
          total = total + Number($(this).val());
        }
      });
    $("#resultado").text(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text"><br>
<p>Total: <span id="resultado"> 0</span></p>
```

Comment: Si no conviertes el valor del input a `Number()`, estás concatenando los valores en vez de sumarlos.

Comment: La verdad el tema me intereso, pero @GeordanoPolanco tu codigo no me da resultado, pero si el de Luis

Comment: Lo que estoy haciendo es agregarle **PHP**, trate de poner el resultado en un **input**, pero no me resulta... hice `<input id="resultado" type="text" name="vTotal">`

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción, no se por que pero no me gusta llamar funciones desde el HTML, prefiero agregar eventos utilizando selectores.

En definitiva, es detectar que cambia el input y sumar todos los valores. De esa forma no tienes que saber si es una suma o una resta.

Te comparto mi solución.

```js
var _EVENT_LISTENERS  = 'keyup change';
var $inputs           = $('.inputs');
var $total_element    = $('#total');

// EVENT LISTENER
$inputs.on(_EVENT_LISTENERS, '.inputs_valors_privisionales', suma_valores);

// ADD ALL INPUT VALUES
function suma_valores() {
  var total         = 0,
    $inputs_valores = $('.inputs_valors_privisionales');

  Array.from($inputs_valores).forEach((el) => {
    total = Number($(el).val()) + Number(total);
  });

  $total_element.text(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs">
        <input type="number" min="-999" max="999" class="inputs_valors_privisionales" value="0" />
        <input type="number" min="-999" max="999" class="inputs_valors_privisionales" value="0" />
        <input type="number" min="-999" max="999" class="inputs_valors_privisionales" value="0" />
        <input type="number" min="-999" max="999" class="inputs_valors_privisionales" value="0" />
        <input type="number" min="-999" max="999" class="inputs_valors_privisionales" value="0" />
    </div>
<h1>Total: <span id="total">0</span></h1>
```